# What are acceptable ways of promoting your Area 51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I have two proposals on Area 51.  I'd like to get the word out about them, however, I don't know of to many Stack Exchange users who would be interested in these sites.  I'm not trying to necessarily ask a subjective question, but what are some effective channels that we can use to at least drive traffic to Area 51?

I have considered posting messages in a few of the chat boards.  Is this considered spam or is that acceptable.  I did do that a couple of times for my "Retro-Gaming" proposal but I stopped because I felt like it might be against the TOS.

Any tips or points-of-clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: These questions are for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com; use the "area51-meta" tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another useful thing to do might be to go through related questions on Stack Exchange sites, like Stack Overflow, and post a comment on the related question.

For example, I started a [Healthcare Industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=0FgbVsKaId7Z_15aCbzplg2)(dododo promotion :P) proposal that would cover Healthcare IT (HIT) topics. I could post links to this on questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208041/membership-providers-and-hipaa-compliance) or [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14376/can-phi-be-hipaa-compliant-on-a-cloud)(which was originally moved from an older HIT proposal). These questions could be better answered on the proposed Stack Overflow site, and the question participates would likely find it relevant to their interests.

With that said, I haven't done this myself yet. I plan to wait until it (hopefully) goes into the commit stage.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about the [API Finder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36863/api-finder) group, no? See, I just promoted it :) In fact I believe I heard about it from one of your questions/answers/comments.

I would suggest promoting it the same way you would promote any other link you wanted other people to know about. You might mention it discreetly in other forums, as long as it was on topic:

> Hey, since we're talking about APIs, I'm trying to help get a new SE
>   site off the ground, here's a link ...

There are plenty of forums that might appreciate it. Just don't overdo it. I know I hate it when people drop links about something only they care about.

Comment: Well, that's part of the problem-- I'm not part of any other forums, really.  Also, I didn't create the API Finder (but I did join it when someone else mentioned it, as you've discovered.)  I could troll forums that are related but, that feels like spamming to me.

Comment: If you're only joining to drop your link, it's artificial and could get you banned ... having said that, this question is very similar to other questions on meta and might get closed.